# What is the return type of this function?

Tags: c++, macros, return

I got this line into a macro definition of a class

```
virtual const char *GetEventName() const
{
    return #classname;
}
```

What is happening in this function and its return type?

Comment: Well, the return type is `const char *`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `classname` is one of the arguements of the macro, `#classname` is a string version of its value. So if `classname` were `SomeType`, `#classname` would be the equivalent of `"SomeType"`

Since it is returning a string (c string) the return type is const char*

For more information look at [Stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

Comment: you are welcome! could you pls mark that as the answer if it has resolved your question?